How to loop to calculate linear regression without learning and increasing the degree of freedom and standard error?
All I want is to automate the calculation of multiple linear regression on groups of data,599 rows each time in 5 columns, without accumulation of standard error and without increasing the degree of freedom when looping over the data group by group. And not the whole rows for each column, because this causes overestimation of the regression coefficients.
I am working on physical data, and I am interested only in the calculation of the regression cofficients for each group (599 rows in 5 columns) without machine learning for prediction. Here you are my code:
for d in range(len(lst)):
    for a,b,c,e,f in zip(temp_list,density_list,Z_list,x2,x3):
          if a==lst[d]:
                density.append(b)
                Z_1.append(c)
                x_2.append(e)
                x_3.append(f)
    independant_variavles = []
    independant_variavles.append(density)
    independant_variavles.append(x_2)
    independant_variavles.append(x_3)
    
    X =np.array(independant_variavles)
    
    X = X.transpose()
     model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
    print("Temperture:  ",temp_unique[d], "Coefficients:  ",model.params, "number of rows or df:  ",model.df_resid)


the output is:
Temperture:   1541.5 Coefficients:   [-3.99307084e-04  3.19782620e-04  6.71098555e-06] number of rows or df:   599.0
Temperture:   1545.3 Coefficients:   [-3.68444754e-04  3.20316004e-04  6.69181306e-06] number of rows or df:   1201.0
Temperture:   1546.8 Coefficients:   [-3.50096899e-04  3.20633181e-04  6.68043142e-06] number of rows or df:   1803.0
Thank you very much!

I am sorry, I found it. Alll to do is to define the lists within the first loop, not before it, to avoid the accumulation!
